# Pycharm does not auto-create documentation stubs

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm not sure why this is happening on this computer; it's never happened on any other. When I try to create a docstring for a function or class in pycharm, nothing happens. I.e.:

```
def foo(bar):
    """"""
    pass
```

Should insert a docstring upon pressing enter; instead it simply does:

```
def foo(bar):
    """
    """
    pass
```

Comment: A) Waaaay not enough information. B) You should file this as a bug report with the IDE.

Comment: What kind of information will be helpful? I didn't want to bother filing this as a bug due to the latency in how long I assume it will take them to reply. It's a Mac machine, on the newest OS, using Anaconda, fully updated. It's a completely fresh install of pycharm, and this is a completely new project.

Comment: You should put all that info in the question, not the comments. The edit button under the tags is just for that sort of thing. Err on the side of verbosity for something like this. Since you don't know what is causing the problem, give us everything. You'll never know what's relevant until someone fixes the problem. Use the same philosophy when filing the bug report.

Comment: Also, it is irresponsible not to file a bug report if you think something is legitimately a bug just because you assume there will be some latency (as likely as not there won't).

Comment: I calibrated the amount of information to what I was expecting, which was "oh yeah that happened to me go to settings > general > ..." as my priors suggest that if this were a bug, and commenting simply doesn't work for on Macs, I would've found it when searching on stackoverflow and elsewhere. I'm reasonably sure this issue is due to a stupid mistake I'm making.

Comment: Fair enough. SO is still not the place for this type of question since it is not really about coding.

Comment: It would help me get back to coding though? :<

Comment: Probably. But so would an [alcohol IV](https://xkcd.com/323/).

Comment: SO is not a place for tautology. The statement "an alcohol IV would help me y" is never false, even if "y" is "stay sober."

Comment: When you say "it's never happened on any other computer", do you mean on other computers, PyCharm did what you wanted? By the way, if your cursor is on "bar", pressing Alt-Enter (on OS X) will bring up a set of "code intentions". One of which is to put type information in the docstring. But I'm not sure if that is your complaint (that you don't get type information).

Comment: Unless you specify a docstring format in preferences (search docstring), it doesn't take variable names from method (at least in 2019.3)

Answer (score 26):

Make sure a docstring format is selected in `File → Settings → Tools → Python Integrated Tools`

Comment: This was the issue for me

Comment: PyCharm -> Preferences -> Python Integrated Tools Docstrings

Answer (score 20):

I was having this same problem for pyCharm 2019.3.1 and I just solved it following this instructions at the [pyCharm site's documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-tools-python-integrated-tools.html)

Specifically at the "**Docstring format**" section, following this:

[image: Docstring format]

Comment: This can be an incredibly annoying bug. This feature can just stop working. Right now I have two projects open. Used to work as expected n both. But all of a sudden it stopped working in one. This happens all too frequently then I have to go find the  documentation to remind myself of this fix.

Comment: Helped in 2022. One more steps: Right clock > Show Context Actions > Add parameters to docstrings (than I've chosen restructured text format)...

Answer (score 19):

In order to solve this problem, I had to go into `Settings → Tools → Python Integrated Tools` and reset the docstring format. I did so by changing `Docstring format` from `Epytext` to `Plain`, clicking `Apply`, then changing it back to `Epytext` again and applying the change, and now everything works.

PyCharm version: 2021.1.2 (Community Edition)

Comment: Didn't work for me! Tried all options, but - alas!..

Comment: @Stanislav Koncebovski I tried it again, and it worked for me on 2021.2.3. Which OS and PyCharm version are you using? Give us more info, many people will find it useful.

Comment: Thanks for your mentioning it. It was a silly error of mine. In PyCharm, instead of the real interpreter path, there was something different which was not aware of automatic docstrings.

Answer (score 4):

This is a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-18486) and should be fixed in 2016.1.1.

One workaround, as described in the issue:

> A workaround for this is to just """  before the code of your first line, then
>   drop that code down a newline when it populates. Clunky, but it is a workaround 
>   for now.

Comment: Yep, that worked. But I have 2021.3 and it's still a problem!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by changing my keyboard preferences on MacOSX from U.S. International - PC to British. The double quotation mark in U.S. International - PC triggers the system to wait for a letter to accent e.g " then  e becomes ë. However, it doesn't seem to behave the same way in all editors.

Mere speculation, but perhaps there is some formatting magic going on in the background in PyCharm which is not working properly because of some additional (also unseen) formatting added when using U.S. International - PC that prevents PyCharm from adding the context it needs to know it should created the docstring after pressing enter?